# How to access recent file path from KDE file chooser dialog?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde

I use GTK-based applications very often. So if need to access last location I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to get into *Recent* items.

But I do not see such option in KDE dialog (from K3b, but it does not really matter):

> [image: k3b open file]

Am I missed something? Is it possible to access recent folder and files from KDE file chooser dialog?

Comment: At first glance, it appears that the KDE file chooser dialog doesn't offer a "Recent" files or folders option.  The closest I can see is not to use the KDE file chooser dialog but instead to use `Alt+F` and look for "recent" or "recently modified" or something similar. If you want to increase/decrease the number of "remembered" items, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/957804/increasing-the-number-of-recently-used-items-in-kde?rq=1

Comment: Looking into this some more … At least with the Kate editor, I can press `Ctrl+O` to bring up a window like you've shown and then, [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9FbK.png), I click on the highlighted icon to ensure that *Show Places Navigation Panel* is checked. After that, if I scroll down (in the left pane), there is a section of entries under *Recently Saved*. In there, I can view files from today, yesterday, this month, and the previous month. I suspect this works in conjunction with the *baloo* file and folder indexer and maybe empty on systems that don't have *baloo* running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KDE file chooser dialog includes the same panels as Dolphin. These are editable through Dolphin.

To have recent files and folders in the KDE dialog all you need is to have them visible in Dolphin. As they can be hidden, be sure they are not.

[image]

[image]

To have the KDE dialog in GTK applications like Firefox, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1150512/925128).